# Linear discriminant analysis in R

Tags: r, discriminant-analysis

I have two matrices, both 46175  * 741 (Rows of variables by columns of individuals/observations). Matrix A contains a categorical (perhaps dependent) variable (0/1/2 or NA) and Matrix B is continuous and independent (Ranging from 0 to a couple 100).

I want to see if there is a relationship between these data. Firstly, am I correct in thinking that LDA in R is a valid way to test this? If so, how exactly do I run this?

```
z <- lda(data= MatrixA , x= MatrixB, grouping=MatrixB)
```

is the closest I've gotten, but it doesn't work. I get:

```
 z <- lda(data= MatrixA , x= MatrixB, grouping=MatrixB)
Error in lda.default(x, grouping, ...) : 
  nrow(x) and length(grouping) are different
```

Data Snippet:

```
 Matrix A -------------------------   
 SampleA    SampleB    SampleC          
   NA          0           1
   NA          NA          NA
   1           2           0
   0           0           0 

  Matrix B -----------------------
  SampleA    SampleB    SampleC          
   0          0           0
   83         124         56
   39         45          5
   12714      12477       8751
```

The matrices contain data on the same individiuals, in the same order of columns and rows. Matrix A contains genotypes (genetic information) that is either 0/1/2 or could not be obtained (NA). MatrixB is the  number of reads aligned to that region. Zero in this is therefore not the same as zero in MatrixA and is more similar to its NA.

Comment: It "doesn't work"? What happens? What error messages do you get? What is the `str` of MatrixA and MatrixB ? What *are* those matrices?

Comment: I added the error message I get. Is that because of the NAs? Removing NAs in MatrixA and 0's in MatrixB (which is equivalent) does not yield matrices of the same dim. The str of both is '46175 obs. of  741 variables: with all integers.

Comment: Why not just plot the distributions of B for A = 0, 1, 2, NA side by side?

Comment: The data is too big to plot(MatrixA, MatrixB). I get a "Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large" returned. How would you suggest I plot the distributions? Just a histogram?

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems here.

- Each row should correspond to one case/individual; each column to one variable.
  If I understand your description correctly, that means you need to transpose your data.
- This also means that you have more variates than individuals, thus the variance-covariance matrix is not of full rank which leads to problems during its inversion inside `lda`.
  You need to drastically reduce the number of variates or increase the number of individuals before performing LDA (if I correctly understood your description of the data).
- `MASS::lda` expects grouping to be a factor with one value per case (= row), not a matrix.
  That's why it is complaining that `length (grouping)` is not the same as `nrow (x)`
- It does not make any sense to give the same data for `x` and `grouping`: `x` should be the matrix with the independent variates, `grouping` is the dependent.
- It is very unusual to give `x`, `grouping` *and* `data`.
  Either give `data` and `formula`: with that you call the formula interface (`lda.formula`).
  *Or* give `x` and `grouping`: that calls `lda.default` (a bit faster than the first option).

---

edit:

The formula version `lda (grouping ~ x)` is equivalent to `lda (x = x, grouping = grouping)`. If you have a data.frame `data` with columns `x` and `grouping`, then you'd use `lda (grouping ~ x, data = data)`. Note that a column of a data.frame can hold a whole matrix.

Comment: I know it's more normal to give the formula, but how do you construct that? Do you know what I should write given the data I have? ;

Comment: @pepsimax: I suspect that I still did not understand what your data is like, so I'm not completely sure a) wheter LDA is appropriate, nor b) how you should construct your call. Maybe you could show us a small part of your matrices?

Comment: Sorry, I thought my description was clear. Ive added some sample data. Having less variates that individuals will mean I will lose a lot of information surely?

Comment: @pepsimax: Having less variates than individuals means that you cannot distinguish between random differences betrween individuals and "real" effects. What is the meaning of the rows in your matrices?

Comment: I alluded to what the rows are in the update.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the allusion. Please explain unambiguously what your data are, otherwise we have no chance to answer your question.